# Map domain onto unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to map the domain $D=\mathbb{C}\backslash\{iy:\ y\geq 0\}$ onto the unit disc. I know that there are fast ways to do so but I am specifically interested in whether the following is correct:

1. I rotate $D$ via $\varphi_1(z)=iz$ to get $\mathbb{C}^{-}$.
2. I use the principal branch of the logarithm $\varphi_2(z)=\log(z)$ to map it further to the horizontal stripe between $-i\pi$ and $i\pi$.
3. I scale and shift the stripe using $\varphi_3(z)=\frac{1}{2}z+i\frac{\pi}{2}$ to get the horizontal stripe between $0$ and $i\pi$.
4. Then via the exponentialfunction $\varphi_4(z)=\exp(z)$ I map this stripe onto the upper half-plane $\mathbb H^+$.
5. Lastly via the Cayley-Transform $\varphi_5(z)=\frac{z-i}{z+i}$ we get from the upper half-plane to the unit-disc.

In total the function $\phi:=\varphi_5\circ\varphi_4\circ\varphi_3\circ\varphi_2\circ\varphi_1$ should get me from $D$ to the unit disc. Is this correct?

Comment: your domain is a slit plane, i.e. the plane minus a half-line. How can this be rotated to a half plane via $\varphi_1$?

Comment: Why half plane? Maybe my notation is uncommon, but $\mathbb{C}^{-}=\mathbb{C}\backslash\{x:\ x\leq 0\}$.

Comment: Oh ok. I thought you meant the lower half plane (negative imaginary part). Btw i think your map works